# replace values within the same column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to do something like this with dplyr (data set = COL, variable = SEX):

```
COL[COL$SEX == "MACHO","SEX"] <- "M"
COL[COL$SEX == "HEMBRA","SEX"] <- "F"
```

Should be simple but this is? in the only command line? the best I can do at the moment. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of multiple assignments, an option is to convert to `factor` with `levels` and `labels` specifying

```
COL$SEX <- factor(COL$SEX, levels = c("MACHO", "HEMBRA", labels = c("M", "F"))
```

---

Or another option is to convert to a logical vector, then change it to numeric index by adding 1, and replace the values based on the index

```
COL$SEX <- c("M", "F")[1 + (COL$SEX == "HEMBRA")]
```